# RoboVM crash after splash screen on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, libgdx, robovm

I was trying to put an iOS app on my iPhone with RoboVM. The app is working in my iOS simulator, but when I try on the phone the app simply crashes after the splash screen.

I also got this error:

```
03/06/14 8:40:38 PM: [ERROR] AppLauncher failed with an exception:
03/06/14 8:40:38 PM: [ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected response from debugserver: $X00;description:5465726d696e617465642064756520746f207369676e616c2036;#00
03/06/14 8:40:38 PM: [ERROR]    at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.launchInternal(AppLauncher.java:708)
03/06/14 8:40:38 PM: [ERROR]    at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.launch(AppLauncher.java:814)
03/06/14 8:40:38 PM: [ERROR]    at org.robovm.compiler.target.ios.AppLauncherProcess$1.run(AppLauncherProcess.java:67)
```

I'm on iOS 8 and I use LibGDX.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: RoboVM has not been tested on iOS 8 yet and I don't think it will be supported for quite some time. You will have to downgrade to iOS 7 for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

Update your roboVM version to 1.0.0-alpha-04 or newer

Answer (score 1):

OK, for my case, I've found a solution.
This error message seems to be nothing more than a failed assert thrown by the iOS system (at least in my case; and the error description number `$X00;description:5465726d696e617465642064756520746f207369676e616c2036;#00` is exactly the same). The exact failed assert was not being shown or detailed when running from the device, but when I realized (that's dumb from me, I know, but I tend to develop just for Android) that I could launch the XCode simulator (XCode 6, iOS8) from Eclipse, I saw a clear message when running the app:

```
Assertion failed! File: .../libgdx/gdx/jni/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2ChainShape.cpp, Line 63. Expression: b2DistanceSquared(v1, v2) > 0.005f * 0.005f
```

The crash was solved by fixing this Box2D related problem; in this case it was that I was creating a Loop specifying both start and end vertices at the same position, while the documentation says this must not be done when specifying a looped `b2ChainShape` (which will be closed automatically). I wasn't getting this problem with the Android Box2D binary; it either does not have the assertion messages enabled, or it's ignoring the fact I was trying to create a looped chain in a wrong way. I suggest you debug your app with the latest XCode, LibGDX (stable 1.4.1 as of yesterday) and RoboVM version (1.0.0-alpha-4 for the time being), and try to understand any assertion failed messages you may get, which will not show up when running from the device.